# Linking Cloud Conslole project with an App Engine Application

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-endpoints

Hi I'm a bit confused between App engine Dashboard and Cloud Console.
I've an android application which uses a cloud console project for various api accesses (like Google+, Google Play Games etc..).

Now I want to build an App Engine back end for my app.

When I tried to create a new Application in App Engine Dashboard it says invalid project id.
I hope it was because I have the same project id for my Cloud Console project.

So I'm a bit confused here. How can I create an App Engine Application with the same project-id. Or is there any method to link the existing Cloud Console Project with a new App Engine Application.

I'm a beginner with App Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that Cloud Console id's and GAE id's do not share the same namespace.  So, if GAE tells you that your id is taken it means that someone else has already claimed it and that you will need to use a different id.

Once you have created your GAE project, you can go to the bottom of the settings page and create a new console project that will then be associated with your GAE project.  If you created your console project first then I believe there is no way to associate it with your GAE project but that's OK because they can still be used together - the whole idea of explicitly associating the two is rather new and not necessary.

Comment: Yes Tom. I think you are right. Someone might have used that id already. But that was a distant probability considering how I constructed mine. Anyways I'll create new app and use it. Till now I was thinking that both console project and GAE app needs to share same ID. Thanks Tom for your reply.

Comment: @Sreekanth no problem.  if that answers your question then please mark it as answered.